# php sum of multiple outputs of the function

Tags: php

I have the following code:

```
<?php

class test{


//here we get the total price for the amount, and print-it on screen
public function priceProd($amount){
    if (!empty($amount)) {
        $price = 5;
        }

    //getting the sum and outputed using echo
    $sum = $price * $amount;
    echo $sum.'<br>';


    //building the array
    $answer = array();
    $answer['sum'] = $sum;

}


//here we get the total price for all the values outputed by the priceProd function
public function sumProd(){ 



}


 //closing the class
 }


 $test = new test;

 //feeding amount values to function and getting multiple sums 
 echo $test->priceProd(2);
 echo $test->priceProd(4);

 //getting all the total of sums
 echo $test->sumProd();


 ?>
```

How do I make that the function sumProd makes the sum of all the outputs of the function priceProd. Now, even if the example of the function is not complete, it seem to take and output only the last value of $sum. If I use a database to store all the values, i think is more simpler, but with an raw output like this, I don't know how to find the answer.

Any type of answers are welcomed. Thank you very much!

Comment: You have 2 return in the product(...) function?

Comment: use array for return multiple values

Comment: Yes, or even more that 2. And in my example only the last return it's entering the sumProd.

Comment: Because maybe is the first try of oop that i make, i have difficulty to understand some basic functioning. So the array should be inside the priceProd()? then return'it to sumProd() where i read every value of the array and make the sum?

Comment: if you want to get `sum of amount` than why are you using `string` and `concat (.)` ? .. you should first define `public $sum = 0` and than use `$sum = $sum+($amount*$price);`

Comment: I could not make it work, i could not use the array and sum the values. It seems very simple, but I do not understand what i'm doing wrong. I've reposted a more simpler example.

Answer (score 2):

you should use `array` as the return value of your function..

like.

```
$answer = array();
$answer['sum'] = $sum;
$answer['price'] = $price;
$answer['product'] = $product;

return $answer;
```

Comment: Also, it is notable that the moment the `<br>` is added to the number, the number becomes a string -

Comment: Yeah, but good luck mathematically adding a string to an int. e_e

Comment: that <br> is only for visual orientation.

Answer (score 0):

Let me clarify some things:

1). You can't return twice in a function. (see product function, below)

a). One function to print a subtotal calculated by amount*price - 
b). Another function to print the total expense.

This will work:

class test{

```
private $total = array(); 

public function product($product, $amount){
    echo $amount.' - '.$product.' - ';

  $this->amount = $amount;
  $this->product = $product;
 return; // if you need this to return a value, put it here. 
}



public function priceProd($product){
$amount = $this->amount;

if ($product == 'pen') {
    $price = 10;
} elseif ($product == 'gum') {
    $price = 5;
}

$sum = $price * $amount;
$this->total = $this->total + $sum; 
return $this->price = $sum.'<br>';

}



public function sumProd(){ 

    return $this->total; 
// or, from the looks of the rest, you probably want to: 
       echo "Total: ".$this->total;


    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for direct example:  I now have something that bothered me even in my previously tests: Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in "$this->total = $this->total + $sum;"

Comment: Hmm. You may need to copy+paste that in, somewhere. That'll very likely be a typo-ed character.